# Abducted woman calls man with damaged phone for help, has only one call

Tags: identify-this-movie

It's actually been quite long since I saw this movie, probably around 10 years or so. I saw it in German TV, which means it was at least 2 years old when it aired. Production country is presumably the US.

Here's what I remember about the movie:

- A woman was abducted and kept in the attic of a wooden house (a farm maybe?).
- She had a broken phone (rotary dial?) which she used to call someone for help.
- The man she reached didn't know the woman.
- In one scene, his phone battery was almost dead so he went into a store and stole a car charger (he stole it because it would have taken too long to wait in line).
- Pretty sure the woman emphasized that this was the only call she could make.
- I think there was something about the woman's son as well, but I'm not sure about that.

That's about all I know, I hope you can work with what I provided.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Cellular](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337921/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

Kim Basinger is the kidnapped woman and Jason Statham is one of the kidnappers.

Trailer:

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_(film))

> Jessica Martin (Kim Basinger), a high school biology teacher, takes
>   her son Ricky to his bus stop for school. After she returns home,
>   several men break into her house, kill her housekeeper, **and confine
>   Jessica in the attic of their safe house.** Ethan Greer (Jason Statham),
>   the group leader, **smashes the attic's telephone. Jessica uses the
>   wires of the broken phone and randomly dials a number.** She reaches the
>   cell phone of Ryan Ackerman (Chris Evans), a carefree young man who
>   has just been dumped by his girlfriend, Chloe (Jessica Biel).

Full movie is on Youtube here:

At 0:31:35 Chris Evans storms into a store and demands a charger.

Comment: This video's splash frame looks like kind of spoiler.

Comment: Full movie on youtube?? It seems DMCA has been too busy to look under its nose